# Unexpected '/' in environment variables

Tags: r, path

Every time I restart R, I get a message in the console:

```
Error: 2:24: unexpected '/'
2: Sys.setenv(BINPREF = C:/
```

I've tried unsetting `BINREF` (Sys.unset...) or setting to an empty string, or adding a double backslash when setting (`\\`) but the error persists.

This is what it is currently set to: `C:\Rtools\mingw_$(WIN)\bin\`

It was set with:

```
cat('Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/Rtools/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/")',
    file = file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".Rprofile"), 
    sep = "\n", append = TRUE)
```

What can I do? Is there anyway I can delete `BINPREF`?

Comment: Is the path surrounded with quotes?

Comment: Where? When I call `Sys.getenv()` it prints the variables with no quotes. But when I set it originally it was surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with

```
cat('Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/Rtools/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/")',
    file = file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".Rprofile"), 
    sep = "\n", append = FALSE)
```

Creates new .Rprofile